# Which view should register for keyboard notification

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard

I have a navigation controller (A) whose parent view controller (not visible) presents another navigation controller as modal form sheet (B).

Well I'm trying to figure out how to move the modal view controller up so fields aren't obscured by keyboard, but I'm not sure which view to listen to the keyboard notifications on, and hence should be responsible for moving the navigation controller (B).

As an additional issue, I'm not sure that I even can move a modal form sheet view controller.  I tried changing its frame, but that didn't do anything.

The code inside (A) that presents (B) is here...

```
    imageEditor.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
    imageEditor.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageEditor];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
    navController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
    navController.preferredContentSize = imageEditor.view.frame.size;

    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^(void){ }];
```

How do I proceed here?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A form sheet should automatically scroll up when the keyboard appears. There is nothing you need to do to make that happen.

Comment: @rmaddy  I edited my code to show how I'm presenting (B), and it's not moving out of the way, as my screenshot shows, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Minor confusion on my part. The form sheet only moves if the iPad is in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I used awhile back, you can modify it to work for your case. Essentially I'm calculating the intersection of the keyboard and my view, and then animating the views y-axis up to compensate for the keyboard.

```
#pragma mark - Keyboard Event Responses

-(void)observeKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(respondToKeyboardAppearanceNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(respondToKeyboardDisappearanceNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)respondToKeyboardAppearanceNotification:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    // Workaround to the invalid animation curve returned below (<< 16). Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/878410#878410
    NSUInteger tmpOption = [[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    CGRect tmpKeyboardBeginFrame = [[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect tmpKeyboardEndFrame = [[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    if(fabs(tmpKeyboardBeginFrame.origin.y- tmpKeyboardEndFrame.origin.y) < 50) {
        // iOS 9 fires this notification when the first responder changes even if the keyboard is present
        // This check will stop the appearance block from firing if the keyboard isn't actually appearing
        return;
    }
    CGFloat heightAdjustment = [self intersectionOfView:self keyboardRect:tmpKeyboardEndFrame].size.height;
    self.alertCenterY.constant = -heightAdjustment;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:(tmpOption << 16)
                     animations:
    ^{
        [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
     }
                     completion:nil];
}

-(void)respondToKeyboardDisappearanceNotification:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    // Workaround to the invalid animation curve returned here (<< 16). Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/878410#878410
    NSUInteger tmpOption = [[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    self.alertCenterY.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[[inNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:(tmpOption << 16)
                     animations:
     ^{
         [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
     }
                    completion:nil];
}


- (CGRect)intersectionOfView:(UIView *)inView keyboardRect:(CGRect)inKeyboardRect {
    CGRect tmpSelfFrame = CGRectZero;
    CGRect tmpKeyboardFrame = inKeyboardRect;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        // Infer the keyboard's position in landscape. As it's attached to the window, its frame is fixed in portrait.
        tmpKeyboardFrame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetWidth([self.window frame]) - CGRectGetWidth(tmpKeyboardFrame), CGRectGetHeight(tmpKeyboardFrame), CGRectGetWidth(tmpKeyboardFrame));
        tmpSelfFrame = inView.frame;
    } else {
        tmpSelfFrame = [self.window convertRect:inView.frame toView:self.window];
    }
    return  CGRectIntersection(tmpKeyboardFrame, tmpSelfFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to wrap your imageEditor content into [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) and get some rest.

It will automatically detect if any UIControl element became a first responder and offset itself to avoid overlapping.

Comment: Wow, I gotta check that out.